# How Much cost to setup trading platform such as Flextrade, portware, Sungaurd or Bloomberg for hedge fund?

Tags: trading-systems, hedge-fund

Basically if someone want to setup a hedge fund how much cost to buy trading software such as Flextrade, portware, Sungaurd or Bloomberg for hedge fund?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the others,but the base for Bloomberg is about 1200/month before any useful real-time data.

Answer (score 0):

EMS users compensate providers, directly or indirectly (by direct payment or directed order flow), an average of $10,000 per month.Traders Magazine. http://www.tradersmagazine.com/news/ems-move-from-front-office-and-into-the-cloud-woodbine-111642-1.html#Login